# Careers 2.0 invitation to email address I'm not using with SO - where from?

Tags: support, jobs, email, invitation

I just got an email titled "Expanding your Reputation" to my work email address - which, IIRC, I never used on any Stack Exchange site.

The email body starts with `In recognition of your contributions to Stack Overflow, we’d like to invite you to create a professional profile on Stack Overflow Careers 2.0.` So I checked my SO profile, and the address registered there is my private one, just as I recalled.

I know that users can invite other users, but since the mail doesn't mention anything about the invite being sent by another user... well, I'm a little bit confused.

If someone could tell me where that invite came from (and if it was meant for me) - I'd really like to know.

**EDIT** I'm not 100% sure, maybe I *did* use my work address at some time. That must have been ages ago though. And I just checked all my SE profiles, none of them showed my work email. Strange.

Comment: Stack Exchange has become sentient! We need to shut down this beast!

Comment: Can you take a look at the E-Mail headers just to make sure there isn't some funny redirection taking place? If you never gave that address to SO, it seems very unlikely it could use it. (unless it's indeed become sentient, but then everything's too late. It'll have killed all employees by now, and replaced them with software. The remote workers will have met an especially gruesome fate, with homicidal kitchenware chasing them through the house)

Comment: Stack Net. Sky Exchange. Waaaaaaah.

Comment: Nah, no funny business with the mail headers, all clear. Email came directly from mx-out.stackexchange.com to my employer's email server. Probably means the toasters must really have taken over SO.